# How to give a specific program more resources

Tags: virtualbox

I would like to give VirtualBox priority over anything else running on my install of Elementary OS. Within VirtualBox, I have dedicated 4GB of ram and 4 CPU cores to my VM, however the VM is still "laggy" while in use. I would like to know if there is a way to either turn off as many services as possible when VirtualBox starts, or if there is a way to give VirtualBox an extremely high priority over anything else running on my computer. Thank you all for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use System Monitor(install from AppCenter) for these. First open System Monitor from Applications, and go click on Processes, and find your VM process, depends on which VM one you using
[image]

Next, right click and choose priority for process as you wish:
[image]

---

So check it out:[image]

Then install it in AppCenter by typing ''gnome-system-monitor'':
[image]

Comment: Hey @predrag can you make a note of which system monitor app you're using and how the OP can install it?

Comment: I am using default EOS System Monitor. There is no need to install it, it comes with EOS. :) You must meaning something else?

Comment: elementary OS doesn't ship with a system monitor installed by default

Comment: You are right. I forget it, that i did install it after OS install from AP.